# Visual Basic Not Saving New Fields to Access Database Added After Initial Linking

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have a Visual Basic program linked to an Access database and everything was working as it was supposed to. However, a new need came up and I had to add a field to the Access database and make it a check box option in my VB form.

I am able to drag the new entry from my Data Source/Data Set in Visual Studio on to the form and when I run the application the initial state of the new checkbox saves (both if it was checked or unchecked by the user).

The problem comes when I try to go back and edit this new checkbox. All other fields will save any changes but if I were to deselect the new checkbox, the change will not save when reopening the database. It seems that I have this issue with any fields that I added to Access after the initial linking of the database.

Any help with determining why the new checkbox will not save changes after initial save will be much appreciated.

The code I'm using to save that works on initial save and edit for all other fields except this new checkbox is:

```
Me.Validate()
Me.ContactsBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ContactEntryDataSet)
```

Comment: VB.NET IsNot vba as explained in the tag text.  That looks like VB.NET code

Comment: Did you re-run the wizard to update your typed `DataSet` after modifying the database schema?  There is a button on the toolbar in the Data Sources window to do that.